# TS-2304 Error - can not find name 'Iterable' in TypeScript while importing "jquery" in ".ts" file

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, npm

I am working on TypeScript version 2.4 using Visual Studio Code as an editor. I installed jQuery with NPM using the following command:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

Then I downloaded the source code of `jquery module` from [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts).

The code of `registrationpage.ts` file is as follows:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
class Registration_Page {
    txtuname: string;
    Registration() {
        $('#table').hide;
        this.txtuname = ( <HTMLTextAreaElement> (document.getElementById('txtusername'))).value;
    }
}
window.onload = () => {
    $('#table').show;
    var bttnLogin = document.getElementById('submit');
    var obj = new Registration_Page();
    bttnLogin.onclick = function () {
        obj.Registration();
    }
}
```

The code for `index.html` is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="registrationpage.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div>
     <fieldset style="font-size: medium; color: #000000;">
        <legend style="background-color:#CCCCFF; font-size: larger;font-weight:bold">Registration Page in TypeScript</legend>
        <br />
        <b>UserName</b>
        <input id="txtusername" type="text" /><br />
        <br />

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`tsconfig.json` file :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]

    }

}
```

When I compile the code on CMD , I get the following error:

> ERROR TS2304 : cannot find the name Iterable

Please suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, I have same issue

Comment: I get this same problem in the VS 2017 UI.  From your answer below it sounds like tsconfig.json is ignored? Can you provide more details o. How to fix this?

Comment: Yes it is ignoring the tsconfig.json file. The solution is to compile the code using command: " tsc -p ."  
please refer : " https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html "

Answer (score 3):

The configuration of `tsconfig.json` is correct. When the target is set to `ES5` and libraries : `es2015,es2015-iterable` are included then `Iterable` is supported. 
The point is when we compile the .ts file by command `tsc "filename"` then "tsconfig.json" is ignored by the compiler. Also, while working with external modules, you need to include the following `js` files to support module loading:

```
https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js">

https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js
```

Lastly, Compile the file with this command

```
**tsc -p .**
```

This command will not ignore `tsconfig.json` file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No one else mentioned that the `tsc` command ignores `tsconfig.json` by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider installing the node type definitions.

`npm i --save-dev @types/node`

If you are using **Yarn** instead of **NPM**:

`yarn add -D @types/node`

Comment: The node typings file defines `Iterable` for the use with `--lib es5` around line 61. See *node_modules/@ types/node/index.d.ts*