# TS2304: Build cannot find name iterable in @types/jquery

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am an old dog trying to learn new tricks (npm, TypeScript, etc).  I am using Visual Studio 2017 with TypeScript 2.5 (project is set to "Latest").  I have a very basic .NET Core 2.0 project I just started working on and have added @types/jquery (3.2.12) to my project but it continues to complain about not being able to find 'Iterable'.  I have read many posts on this subject and how to possibly fix it, including:

[TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/three/three-core.d.ts(767,24): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799041/typescript-error-node-modules-types-three-three-core-d-ts767-24-error-ts230)

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17239

[TS-2304 Error - can not find name 'Iterable' in TypeScript while importing "jquery" in ".ts" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372778/ts-2304-error-can-not-find-name-iterable-in-typescript-while-importing-jque)

My current tsconfig.json contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.iterable"
    ],
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have tried every permutation of libs + target to no avail.  I can get all sorts of other errors but this one, core error never goes away.  I have spent more time trying to get TypeScript to work than it would have taken me to write modules in plain ol' JavaScript.

Is this a .NET Core project/template issue?  How can I tell the IDE is looking at my tsconfig.json file (there are no other such files in the project tree).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I finally gave up on trying to get @types/jquery to work at version 3.0+ and reverted to a jquery 2.0 version just to get the project to compile.  This is pretty lame solution, though, and am still trying to figure out how to solve it for real.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I had to add the `include` section in my `tsconfig.json` and I solved this error. I have the 3.2.1 version of jQuery and 3.2.12 of `@types/jquery`.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "dom", "es2015" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "./Scripts/TypeScript/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I will give that a shot and indicate accepted answer if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Alas, I still have the same issue and for some reason VS flags @types/jquery @3.1.12 as "extraneous" in the solution view.

Comment: Adding "es2015.iterable" to lib fixed it for me: `"lib": [ "dom", "es5", "es2015.promise", "es2015.iterable" ]`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else getting this error, when using an older version of jQuery, you can solve the problem by getting a version specific type file.

For various reasons I have to use jQuery 1.10.2. Using the default @types/jquery gave me version 3.2.16. Therefore I had to get a version 1 specific version by doing:

```
npm install @types/jquery@1.x
```

Similarly version specific types can be downloaded for 2.x and 3.x